# Not getting value when button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Using data binding to get value from another UserControl when the button is clicked

So, I have a UserControl that is nested in another UserControl that is also nested in the main window, that looks like this,

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:InvoiceAppV2.View"

    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem>
                <view:InvoiceControl>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem/>
            <TabItem/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

InvoiceControl xaml:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:InvoiceAppV2.View"
    <Grid>
        <view:BuyerInfoControl/>
    </Grid>

    <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Content="Submit" Click="BtnSubmit_Click"/>
</UserControl>
```

InvoiceControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class InvoiceControl : UserControl
{
    Buyer b = new Buyer();

    public InvoiceUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(b.BuyerName);
    }
}
```

BuyerInfoControl xaml:

```
<UserControl
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Buyer's Name"/>
    <Label Content="Purchase Date"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBuyerName" Text="{Binding Path=BuyerName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                       TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="txtPurchaseDate" Text="{Binding Path=PurchaseDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

Here's the code to handle the property change

```
 public class Buyer: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };   

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public string BuyerName
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if(_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BuyerName"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Buyer() {}

    public Buyer(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        BuyerName = name;
    }

    public Buyer(string name)
    {
        ID = 0;
        BuyerName = name;
    }
}
```

xaml.cs

```
 public partial class BuyerInfoControl : UserControl
{
    Buyer b;
    public BuyerInfoControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        b = new Buyer(txtBuyerName.Text);
        this.DataContext = b;
    }
}
```

when a value of "John Doe" is typed in the TextBox and the button is clicked, the buyer's name is null. I usually work in swfit, object-c and MVC. Trying to figure how to play with MVVM and WPF. I have a feeling I'm doing some wrong here.

Here's the design

[image]

Comment: What's `b` in `InvoiceControl.xaml.cs`? I can see it in `BuyerInfoControl` but not in `InvoiceControl`. Are you sure both controls share the **same instance** of the data context?

Comment: I can't see al the code. What is `b` in _Invoice.xaml.cs_ and is it properly nitialized? Does the `TextBox` _txtBuyerName_  has content?

Comment: It would be better to add a depndency property to the `InvoiceControl` and bind it to `BuyerInfoControl.BuyerName`.

Comment: Ya, where is invoice control on your main page's zaml?

Comment: That `binding` as you call it is a snapshot copy. It doesn't get updated. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`b = new Buyer(txtBuyerName.Text);` only gets the last reference to the state of `Text`; meaning that it is a snapshot.

To achieve proper binding, it has to occur on the main page where the custom control resides and like the TextBox it will need to bind to the source string. To do that one must provide a `Dependency Property` on the custom control.

For example, if a dependency property named `MyText` is added to the control bind like this:

```
 <InvoiceControl MyText="{Binding Path=BuyerName}"/>
 <TextBox x:Name="txtBuyerName" Text="{Binding Path=BuyerName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                   TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
```

Since `InvoiceControl` is a user control, the user control on the main page has to **also** be bound to the originating `BuyerName` (as shown) and to do what you want it has to happen via a dependency property put on `InvoiceControl`.

Wire up a dependency property on `InvoiceControl` as such:

```
#region public string MyText
/// <summary>
/// This the dependency property for the control.
/// </summary>
public string MyText
{
    get { return GetValue(MyTextProperty) as string; }
    set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Identifies the MyText dependency property.
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyText",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(InvoiceControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
#endregion public string MyText
```

then load like this

```
MessageBox.Show(MyText);
```

---

See [Dependancy Property Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview)

---

Also there may be an issue where you are trying to do the button click, right after typing into the control and the proper change event doesn't fire.

In the `TextBox` put in the binding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the so that every text change sends a notification message. That way if one types in and focus moves to the button, the two way binding notification will fire.

---

Note if you work with custom controls this link has Visual Studio snippets which put in fillable templates for dependency properties in the editor. Ignore the title with `Siverlight` and opy the snippets to `C:\Users\{You}\Documents\Visual Studio 20{XX}\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets`, for they **will** work with all versions of visual studio:

[Helpful Silverlight Snippets - Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/)